# Using SED find range and duplicate it

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sed

On Mac OSX but I need to script to be cross platform for linux as there are differences between GNU sed and OSX sed.

I have a file that uses ranged expressions to tell my script to duplicate the whole range. Here's my current solution. I've tried with /a and /i using various - flags and I keep getting multiple address errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
...

stream=$(`cat file.txt`)
for i in 3; do
  stream=$(echo "$stream" | sed '/%%RANGE_STUB/,/%%/ p ')
done
```

As of now this takes my file and duplicates the ranged content **inside** of itself. I need it to go **after**.

Here's the file:

```
Some text here. 

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
```

Here's the output:

```
Some text here.

%%RANGE_STUB
%%RANGE_STUB
%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
%%
%%
```

Here's the desired output:

```
Some text here.

%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
```

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should use awk. Range expressions make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require duplicate conditions or a complete rewrite given the tiniest requirement change and so should be avoided in favor of a flag (trivially implemented in awk). You already know that sed has portability issues so asking for a portable sed solution doesn't make as much sense as just asking for an awk solution.

Comment: yes that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/%%RANGE_STUB/ { inBlock = 1 }
inBlock {
    block = block $0 ORS
    if (/%%$/) {
        for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            print block
        }
        inBlock = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Some text here.

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
```

Comment: I need a variable to pass for the num of times to loop. It'll be dynamic when I'm done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` instead of `sed` on OSX:

```
awk '/%%RANGE_STUB/{p=1} p{s = s RS $0} 1;
     p && /%%$/{for(i=1; i<=3; i++) print s; p=0; s=""}' file

Some text here.

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%

%%RANGE_STUB
This content is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
```

Comment: but is it crossplatform

Comment: Also it's important to keep my for loop because I am writing a script that keeps track of other data. So sticking that for loop inside the awk script is confusing and limiting.

Comment: @Maverick that awk script will work as-is on every awk on every UNIX box. If you need to do more than you've described you should clarify your needs since writing a shell loop just to manipulate text is always the wrong approach (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) so it'd be tough for anyone in good conscience to suggest a solution that employs one given what you've told us so far.

Comment: @Maverick: Yes `awk` is cross platform and calling `sed` or `awk` in a shell for loop is  inefficient if loop runs for long.

Comment: Ok it's cross platform. But no I need the for loop in place.

Comment: If you want to make it inefficient by calling `awk` in a shell loop then you can use: `awk '/%%RANGE_STUB/{p=1} p{s = s RS $0} 1; p && /%%$/{print s; p=0; s=""}' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file` inside your loop.

Comment: To be clear - there's nothing you can do in sed that you can't do in awk. So if you NEED an external shell loop you can have one but so far there's nothing in your question to suggest an external shell loop would be a good idea and it MAY be the case that it's a bad idea - if you provide a more inclusive example we can help you do whatever you're trying to do the best way, whether that does involve a shell loop or not.

Comment: I'm writing a basic script to duplicate stubs and another script to replace the stub contents with array values. So tub 1 will be replaced with the first index of contents, stub 2 with 2ndex, etc... all stubs will have different replacements from the genesis stub

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't mean having an external shell loop would be a good idea. Keep in mind - a shell is simply an environment from which to call tools and manipulate (create/destroy/move) files and processes with a language to sequence those actions, it is NOT a tool to manipulate text which is why it's so slow and difficult to write correctly to do that - the guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text.

Comment: who said anything about an external shell loop this is in bash

Answer (score 0):

For two copies (one duplication pass), no added line breaks:

`echo "$stream" | sed -e '/%%RANGE_STUB/,/%%/{//\!H;/%%RANGE_STUB/h;/%%$/{H;G}}'`

or (different command grouping, same effects):

`echo "$stream" | sed -e '/%%RANGE_STUB/,/%%/{//\!H};/%%RANGE_STUB/h;/%%$/{H;G}'`

What these are doing is:

- `h` -- replace the hold space-- for the first line of the range
- `H` -- append to the hold space-- for the intermediate lines of the range
- `H;G` -- append to hold space, then append entire hold space-- for the final line of the range.

`//\!` is an escaped version of `//!` which means not matching the previous pattern, so it matches intermediate lines in the range.

Your end pattern was changed to `/%%$/` to ensure that it matches only the final line of the range for `H;G`

You get:

```
Some text here.

%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
```

It is very difficult with sed, I think to get 3 copies with repeated script invocations.  You can get powers of 2 by repeating the sed-- every invocation would double the copies.

So for 3 copies, you'd do it in one script:

`echo "$stream" | sed -e '/%%RANGE_STUB/,/%%/{//\!H};/%%RANGE_STUB/h;/%%$/{H;G;G}'`

```
Some text here.

%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
%%RANGE_STUB
This contents is copied and preserved including the RANGE_STUB and double % symbols
%%
```

Conceivably you could construct the string with a variable number of `;G` commands in your wrapper script.

Comment: It may come down to not needing to escape `//!` to `//\!` within a script.  I was testing this as the commandline and the unescaped `! `was causing issues.  Let me know and I'll switch the suggested solutions to unescaped.

Comment: ah ok makes sense. I'm stepping away from the comp for 10 min will update when i get back

Comment: Or this could be a portability issue as @ed-morton mentions.  I tend to enjoy forcing sed to work, but googling for "invalid command code sed" yields all sorts of OSX-unique issues.